# Latex document not producing a second pdf page

Tags: page-breaking

My latex document does not produce a second pdf page when it runs out of space in the first one. When I cut a middle section the text that should appear on the second page appears on the first one without a problem. I also do not get any errors.

Why is this happening?

Here is my Tex for testing.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\mP}{\mathbb{P}}
\newcommand{\calI}{\mathcal{I}}
\newcommand{\partialfrac}[1]{\frac{\partial}{\partial #1}}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\newenvironment{problem}[2][Problem]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}


\begin{document}
We note that, 

\begin{equation*}
\begin{align}
G'(s) = (p-1)|s|^{p-2} sgn(s) s + |s|^{p-1} = p |s|^{p-1} \\
w' = (G (v))' = G'(v) v' = p |v|^{p-1} v'
\end{align}
\end{equation*}

Let $v\in C_c^1(\R)$. Following the hints, we show now that $|v(x)|^p \leq p ||v||^{p-1}_{L^p} ||v'||_{L^p}$


Since $v$ has compact support,

\begin{equation}
        |v(x)|^p = ||v(x)|^{p-1}v(x)| =  ||v(x)|^{p-1}v(x) - \lim\limits_{x \to -\infty}|v(x)|^{p-1}v(x)|= |[w \, ]_{-\infty}^x|
\end{equation}

By the fundamental theorem of integral calculus:

\begin{equation}
    |[ w\, ]_{-\infty}^x | = | \int_{-\infty}^x w' | = | \int_{-\infty}^x p|v|^{p-1}v' dt| \leq \int_{-\infty}^x |p|v|^{p-1}v' dt| \leq \int_{\R} |p|v|^{p-1}v'| 
\end{equation}

By H\"older inequality, $q = \frac{p}{p-1}$:

\begin{equation}
    p \int_{\R} ||v|^{p-1}v'| = \Big(\int_\R (|v|^{p}) \Big)^{\frac{p-1}{p}}\Big(\int_\R |v'|^p\Big)^{\frac{1}{p}} = p ||v||_{L^p}^{p-1}||v'||_{L^p}
\end{equation}

And by Young's inequality:

\begin{equation}
    p ||v||_{L^p}^{p-1}||v'||_{L^p} \leq p \Big( (p-1)\frac{||v||_{L^p}^p}{p} + \frac{||v'||_{L^p}^p}{p} \Big) \leq p (||v||_{L^p}^p + ||v'||_{L^p}^p) = p||v||_{W^{1,p}}^p
\end{equation}

So we have,

\begin{equation}
    |v(x)| \leq p^{1/p} ||v||_{W^{1,p}}
\end{equation}

\begin{lemma}
    For all $p\in \N$, $p^{1/p} \leq e^{1/e}$
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}
Consider the function $f(x) = x^{1/x} = \exp{ 1/x log (x)}$.
\end{proof}

asdasdasdas
\end{document}
```

Comment: You definitely get an error from that one (or at least I do), `align` is not supposed to be used inside `equation*`, it starts math mode on its own. Also you're missing `\end{document}`.

Comment: > you're missing \end{document}.

Sorry about that, forgot to copy it on the OP question. Regarding the \align, how should I should wirte multiple equations in one go then?

Comment: Use *just* `align` (or `align*` if they should be unnumbered). I.e. remove the outer `\begin{equation*}` and `\end{equation*}`.

Comment: That said, after fixing that I do get a document with two pages, so hard for me to say what could be happening. What exactly happens for you with that example? Do the text run across the footer and out of the page, or is the second page just missing? Can you show the `.log` file?

Comment: never ignore error messages! If you need to ask about an error give the error message from the log, don't describe the pdf output which (as you see) is not normally sensible after an error, Tex only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error.

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, at the moment I posted the question I had no idea where the problem was that is why I had to post it. Ill trim it asap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You had  an `align` environment nested in an `equation*` environment, which is forbidden. You might use `aligned`, but since your equation is not numbered, it's simpler to use `align*` without `equation*`.

I took the opportunity to improve your code. If you have several equations  with short texts between them, you obtain a better vertical spacing using a single `gather(*)`environment, and the texts inside an `\intertext` command.

Also, for a correct spacing, don't add blank lines between `equation`s and the main text. Note that , for the norm of a vector you don't obtain the same result with `|| v ||` as with `\lVert v \rVert`. I defined a `\norm` command (and also an `\abs`  command) with the `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` command from `mathtools` to obtain delimiters which can easily be adjusted to the contents size.

As a result, your text finally fits in a single page anyway…

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textgreek}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools, amsthm, amssymb}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}\lvert\rvert
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}\lVert\rVert
\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\mP}{\mathbb{P}}
\newcommand{\calI}{\mathcal{I}}
\newcommand{\partialfrac}[1]{\frac{\partial}{\partial #1}}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\newenvironment{problem}[2][Problem]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
%If you want to title your bold things something different just make another thing exactly like this but replace "problem" with the name of the thing you want, like theorem or lemma or whatever

\begin{document}

\title{Funktionanalysis Blatt 8}
\author{Bernat Sopena Gilboy, Matrikelnummer: - (Gasth\"orerstudent) }
\maketitle

\begin{problem}{1}
\end{problem}

(a) Let $I \subset \R$ be an interval. We want to show that there is a constant $C$ such that
\begin{equation}
     \norm{u}_{L^\infty} \leq C \norm{u}_{W^{1,p}} \; \forall u \in W^{1,p}(I), \, p = 1, 2 \dots
    \label{ex1}
\end{equation}

Without restriction we can let $I = \R$. Suppose $I \neq \R$ and that we showed (1) for $I = \R$. On one side we have
\begin{gather}
    \norm{Eu}_{L^\infty(\R)} \leq C_1 \norm{Eu}_{W^{1,p}(\R)} \leq C_1 C_2(p, I, \R) \norm{Eu}_{W^{1,p}(I)} \\
\intertext{On the other,}
    \norm{Eu}_{L^\infty(\R)} \geq \norm{Eu}_{L^\infty(I)} = \norm{u}_{L^\infty(I)}
\end{gather}
So letting $C = C_1 C_2$ (\ref{ex1}) follows.

Henceforth, we assume $I = \R$. Let $G(s)\coloneqq |s|^{p-1}s$ and $w\coloneqq G(v)$. We note that
\begin{align*}
G'(s) & = (p-1)|s|^{p-2} \sgn(s) s + |s|^{p-1} = p |s|^{p-1} \\
w' & = (G (v))' = G'(v) v' = p |v|^{p-1} v'
\end{align*}

Let $v \in C_c^1(\R)$. Following the hints, we show now that $|v(x)|^p \leq p \norm{ v}^{p-1}_{L^p} \norm{v'}_{L^p}^{\vphantom{p}}$.
Since $v$ has compact support,
\begin{gather}
        |v(x)|^p = \abs{|v(x)|^{p-1}v(x)}= \abs[\Big]{|v(x)|^{p-1}v(x) - \lim_{x \to -\infty}|v(x)|^{p-1}v(x)}= \abs*{[w \, ]_{-\infty}^x}. \\
\intertext{By the fundamental theorem of integral calculus:}
    \abs*{[ w\, ]_{-\infty}^x } = \abs[\Big]{ \int_{-\infty}^x w' } = \abs[\Big]{\int_{-\infty}^x p|v|^{p-1}v' dt} \leq \int_{-\infty}^x \abs*{p|v|^{p-1}v' dt} \leq \int_{\R}\abs*{p|v|^{p-1}v'}. \\
\intertext{By Hölder inequality, $q = \frac{p}{p-1}$:}
    p \int_{\R}\abs*{|v|^{p-1}v'} = \Bigl(\int_\R (|v|^{p}) \Bigr)^{\!\frac{p-1}{p}}\Bigl(\int_\R |v'|^p\Bigl)^{\!\frac{1}{p}} = p \norm{v}_{L^p}^{p-1}\norm{v'}_{L^p}, \\
\intertext{and by Young's inequality:}
    p \norm{v}_{L^p}^{p-1}\norm{v'}_{L^p} \leq p \Bigl( (p-1)\frac{\norm{v}_{L^p}^p}{p} + \frac{\norm{v'}_{L^p}^p}{p} \Bigr) \leq p (\norm{v}_{L^p}^p + \norm{v'}_{L^p}^p) = p\norm{v}_{W^{1,p}}^p. \\
\intertext{So we have,}
    |v(x)| \leq p^{1/p} \norm{v}{W^{1,p}}
\end{gather}
\begin{lemma}
    For all $p\in \N$, $p^{1/p} \leq e^{1/e}$.
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}
Consider the function $f(x) = x^{1/x} = \exp{ 1/x \log (x)}$.
\end{proof}

asdasdasdas

\end{document}
```

[image]